# Service - (After killing application)

Tags: android, service

I want to start an Android Service after killing the application and close service after done specific method.

If it's possible then a snippet or a sample would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio:
Choose File > New > Service > Service.

Give it a name then click finish.
It will now create a new class with the name you entered and register it in the manifest for you.

All you have to do now is override onStartCommand and return the integer constant START_STICKY to let the system know you would like the service to be running even after the application is removed from recents...

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Now you can stop the service anywhere in your code calling stopSelf();